# Can a semi-conductor cooler be powerful enough for a room?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, cooling, machine-design, semiconductor

I see semiconductors used for small fridges. I cannot find one large enough to cool a room (in place of a conventional Freon based, window air-conditioner). What engineering problems might a up scaled version of this devise in the picture may have? What are to pros and cons like no moving parts by using larger heat sinks?
[image]

Comment: They are super inefficient.

Comment: the key problem besides the lack of a COP (air conditioners move more heat than the electricity they consume) is that you have to exhaust the heat somewhere.